# Deserialize CSV string to an C# Object

Tags: c#, .net, deserialization, jira

I have a response from `Jira API`, require to be deserialized into data model:

```
com.atlassian.greenhopper.service.sprint.Sprint@40675167[id=10151,rapidViewId=171,state=CLOSED,name=Sprint 37.1,startDate=2015-07-30T16:00:22.000+03:00,endDate=2015-08-13T16:00:00.000+03:00,completeDate=2015-08-13T14:31:34.343+03:00,sequence=10151]
```

This is actually the information of current sprint for issue.
I need to deserialize it to a model like:

```
public class Model
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

I have already removed all non-required information, like `com.atlassian.greenhopper.service.sprint.Sprint@40675167` using `Regex pattern \[(.*?)\]` so I have brackets and all inside.

Now I stopped completely trying to find the a way to convert this string to a data model.

Comment: Should it not be giving you response data in Json? Simple to deserialze that.

Comment: Cause I'd tried everything, even replacement of symbols

Comment: [JIRA REST API Example - Create Issue](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-create-issue) shows responses in Json format. Use a Json deserializer and you are done.

Comment: Try the .NET SDK - https://bitbucket.org/farmas/atlassian.net-sdk/wiki/Home

Comment: @adricadar you believe split is the best way here? No other options?

Comment: @crashmstr - this is JIRA SDK, not Jira Agile. This response is comming from (yes) Jira API, bt contains data generated by Agile plugin.

Comment: @EvgeniyLabunskiy You say "Jira API", and the first search results are the REST api (which is seperate from Jira Agile). Searching for "Jira SDK" shows only Atlassian SDK. So really hard to tell what you are doing and how you get that particular response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the following [thread](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/204646/sprint-field-value-rest-api) at the Atlassian Answers page and there appears to be no JSON representation of that inner Object. As shown in the example from that thread:

```
customfield_10007:[
"com.atlassian.greenhopper.service.sprint.Sprint@a29f07[rapidViewId=<null>,state=CLOSED,name=NORD - Sprint 42,startDate=2013-07-29T06:47:00.000+02:00,endDate=2013-08-11T20:47:00.000+02:00,completeDate=2013-08-14T15:31:33.157+02:00,id=107]",
"com.atlassian.greenhopper.service.sprint.Sprint@769133[rapidViewId=<null>,state=ACTIVE,name=NORD - Sprint 43,startDate=2013-08-14T15:32:47.322+02:00,endDate=2013-08-23T15:32:47.322+02:00,completeDate=<null>,id=117]"
],
```

The response is indeed a JSON array, but the array itself contains CSV's, so you can make use of the following to parse that:

```
   public class DataObject
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string rapidViewId { get; set; }
        public string state { get; set; } 
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string startDate { get; set; }
        public string endDate { get; set; }
        public string completeDate { get; set; }
        public string sequence { get; set; }
    }


    public class Program
    {
        private const string sampleStringData =
            @"[id=10151,rapidViewId=171,state=CLOSED,name=Sprint 37.1,startDate=2015-07-30T16:00:22.000+03:00,endDate=2015-08-13T16:00:00.000+03:00,completeDate=2015-08-13T14:31:34.343+03:00,sequence=10151]";


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dataObject = new DataObject();

            string[][] splitted;
            var sampleWithNoBrackets = sampleStringData.Substring(1,sampleStringData.Length-2);
            splitted = sampleWithNoBrackets.Split(',').Select(p => p.Split('=')).ToArray();

            dataObject.id           = splitted[0][1];
            dataObject.rapidViewId  = splitted[1][1];
            dataObject.state        = splitted[2][1];
            dataObject.name         = splitted[3][1];
            dataObject.startDate    = splitted[4][1];
            dataObject.endDate      = splitted[5][1];
            dataObject.completeDate = splitted[6][1];
            dataObject.sequence     = splitted[7][1];

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Here's the output for the above:

[image]