# Writing and converting Data from csv file to an array to work with the data c#

Tags: c#

I try to continue my project for the school.

I was able to import the data from a CSV file in the command line. I am really not entirely sure if I wrote it to the array already. But for the next step I need to go ahead and filter the data from the written class. As first example I try to filter the written data over the date (datum) from the class.

I have really no idea what to do now to work. So in the section:

```
 if (decideTyp == "Z")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Decide to filtering date");
                var inputWert = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Filtering the date and show the date: ");
                
                //Console.WriteLine($" {eineAktie.Aktienkurs_datum} {eineAktie.Aktien_id} {eineAktie.Name} {eineAktie.Wert}" /*+ eineAktie.Aktienkurs_datum*/);
                //Console.WriteLine($" {zweiteAktie.Aktienkurs_datum} {zweiteAktie.Aktien_id} {zweiteAktie.Name} {zweiteAktie.Wert}" /*+ eineAktie.Aktienkurs_datum*/);
```

From my code I try to give out all the dates from my CSV file.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace aktienportfolio
{
    public class Aktie
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Datum { get; set; }
        public string Markt { get; set; }
        public string Symbol { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public double Wert { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("AktienProgramm: ");
            Console.WriteLine("--------------- ");
            Console.WriteLine("\n");

            string firstDecide; //StockExchange or Portfolio

            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Do you like take a look at (A)ktienKurse or (P)ortfolio abfragen? \n");
                firstDecide = Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar.ToString().ToUpper();      //Kein Casesensitiv mit ToLower.
                Console.WriteLine(firstDecide);
            }
            while (firstDecide != "A" && firstDecide != "P");     

            if (firstDecide == "A")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nDo you choose StockExchange, please push enter and the data will loaded adnd shown! \n");
                var inputWert = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("\nhere you see your data\n");

                //Read File
                string path = @"C:\Auftrag\Aktienkurse.csv";
                string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(path);
                foreach (string s in readText)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(s);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nyou choose Portfolio, push Enter and the data will be loaded and shown! \n");
                var inputWert = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("\nhere you see your portfolio \n");

                //read File
                string path = @"C:\Auftrag\Portfolio.csv";
                string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(path);

                foreach (string s in readText)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(s);
                }
            }

            //Progamm proceed
            string decideTyp; //Question what the user like to do now
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nDo you like filter the (Z)data through the date or the (I)content  ");
                entscheidungsTyp = Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar.ToString().ToUpper(); 
                Console.WriteLine(entscheidungsTyp);
            }
            while (decideTyp != "Z" && decideTyp != "I"); 

            if (decideTyp == "Z")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("you've chosen the date filtering ");
                var inputWert = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Show the data date: ");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("you decided to show the content");
                var inputWert = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("show the content: ");
            }

            Console.ReadKey(false);
        }
    }
}
```

I am really a beginner so excuse my such dumb questions. I appreciate any help or suggestions to go ahead with my project for the school.

Here are the CSV files:

**Aktienkurse**

```
Id ";" Datum ";" Markt ";" Symbol ";" Name ";" Wert
1;2021-01-10;DowJones;BA;Boeing;135.20
2;2021-01-10;Nasdaq;MSFT;Microsoft;165.13
3;2021-01-10;Nasdaq;AMD;Advanced Micro Devices;48.79
4;2021-01-10;SMI;ABB;ASEA BROWN BOVERI;17.20
5;2021-01-10;DAX;BMW;Bayerische Motoren Werke AG;49.10
6;2021-01-11;Nasdaq;MSFT;Microsoft;166.13
```

**Portfolio**

```
Id ";" Datum ";" Symbol ";" Anzahl
1;2021-01-10;MSFT;45
2;2021-01-6;AMD;23
3;2021-01-7;BMW;10
4;2021-01-5;AMD;30
```

Comment: Could you include some sample text from your .csv file? What have you tried so far? What do you want the output to look like?

Comment: You can even refactor code into english words

Comment: Sure, just a moment

Comment: Hope i translated and explained good enough

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32524313/deserialize-csv-string-to-an-c-sharp-object) help?

Answer (score 0):

I just refactor a project that deals with CSV, but I couldn't refactor everything to pretend it's your CSV, so u can use this as inspiration
Try something like this:

```
public class CSVModel
    {
        public string FirstRow { get; set; }
        public string SecondRow { get; set; }
        public string ThirdRow { get; set; }

    }

    private void ImportFromCSV()
    {

      

        var csv = new CSVModel();

        var csvFile = File.ReadAllLines(txtPath.Text);

         //let's say it's separated by comma
        var file = csvFile[i].Split(',');
        for (int i = 0; i < csvFile.Count(); i++)
        {
            csv.FirstRow = file[i];
            csv.SecondRow = file[i];
            csv.ThirdRow = file[i];
//PS: All properties will have the same value, this isn't the exact solution, 
//just a enlightening
```

}

// here you use the data as you want

}

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I am sure, some good insights will help me a lot to continue my project.
I think i will not be able to solve all problems, because the time is really short to finish the project. But everything I will be able to do or understand c# better will help me through this project.

Once Again, thanks for the input. Will try tomorrow. Was the entire day with struggling at this project :)

Comment: Okay, just ask if you need help.
or you can Google first :)